# Unable to validate salesforce credentials in power bi service

Tags: powerbi, salesforce, datasource, credentials

I am creating a power bi report with multiple tables sources from web and salesforce. when I publish the report and set schedule refresh, I was asked to update data source credentials. I have updated credentials for web data sources. but when i update credentials for salesforce, its giving me an error

[image]

I am able to validate the same credentials in power bi desktop and it works without any issue. but only on power bi service, I am getting this error. Not sure what could be the issue here. please help.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Salesforce, find the connecting user and at the bottom there should be login history. Do you see any errors there? Maybe "Restricted IP" (ask your SF admin to check this user's profile & allowed login IP ranges), maybe "Security token required" (ask sf admin, there's something you need to append at the end of password)...

If your app uses "connected app" (set of OAuth2 keys) there might be some config in SF needed like "all users can self authorise" or add your server to list of allowed callback urls...

Comment: i can see the error under login history which says "Failed: Invalid Nonce". please help me how to fix this

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261547/expired-authorization-code-and-invalid-nonce-errors sounds like logic bug in the login code. A nonce is optional param, never had problems with it. This integration is written from scratch, you control all calls, you created the connected app, know what OAuth scopes and response types you send? Or is it some power BI plugin you don't control, you'd have to contact creators? If you can configure the connected app in SF maybe you could extend the validity of the authorisation code...